# IE error with rallyGrid

Tags: extjs, rally

I'm getting an error with an SDK2.0 app using a rally custom grid:

It only errors with IE (current), and it does not error if I run it locally, only when I install it in Rally and run it.

I don't know if its a Rally issue, or a EXTJS issue.

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'modelField': object is null or undefined 
sdk.js, line 4 character 1276692

The code that failed:

```
if(e.modelField&&e.modelField.hidden)
```

Context around that error:

```
{xtype:"rallytextfield",allowBlank:false,removeNameAttribute:true}}},PortfolioItem:function(){return{hidden:true}},AttributeType:function(b){return a.apply(Rally.ui.grid.FieldColumnFactory.defaultRenderer(b),{sortable:false})}})})();(function(){var a=window.Ext4||window.Ext;var b=function(g,e){var d=g.text;var c=e.text;if(d>c){return 1}if(d<c){return -1}return 0};a.define("Rally.ui.grid.ColumnBuilder",{requires:["Ext.Array","Ext.util.Format","Rally.ui.grid.FieldColumnFactory"],constructor:function(){this.defaultColumns=[];this.autoAddAllModelFieldsAsColumns=true},withDefaultColumns:function(c){if(a.isArray(c)){this.defaultColumns=this.defaultColumns.concat(c)}return this},withSortableColumns:function(c){this.sortable=c;return this},shouldAutoAddAllModelFieldsAsColumns:function(c){this.autoAddAllModelFieldsAsColumns=c;return this},build:function(d){var e=a.Array.map(this.defaultColumns,function(g){if(a.isString(g)){return Rally.ui.grid.FieldColumnFactory.getColumnConfigFromField(d.getField(g),this.sortable)}return g},this);if(this.autoAddAllModelFieldsAsColumns){var c=this._buildModelColumns(d,this.defaultColumns,e);e=e.concat(c)}this._removeHiddenColumns(e);return this._stripTagsFromColumnText(e)},_removeHiddenColumns:function(d){for(var c=d.length-1;c>0;c--){var e=d[c];if(e.modelField&&e.modelField.hidden){a.Array.erase(d,c,1)}}}
```

Not sure what other guidance I can provide to help locate this issue.

Comment: Looking at the context, I would guess this is in the Rally glue to EXTJS

Comment: Can you post the entire app? I tried playing around with the SDK grid in IE9 and I can't seem to get it to break in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was a bit large, so I started to do some divide and conquer before I posted it and I found the cause in my code, though probably not the root cause:

In my columnCfgs when adding the rallygrid, I had a trailing ',' on the last entry.

The really annoying thing is this works in all browsers locally, but only fails in IE on Rally with a super obscure error, so its really hard to chase down...even my JavaScript syntax highlighter did not warn me...

I suspect this is actually a problem in either Rally or EXT-JS code where IE is just really finicky...

Comment: IE is pretty infamous for not allowing trailing commas. The spec actually does allow it, but IE does it's own thing here. I'm surprised it ran fine locally in IE. If you run your code through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/), it will warn you of trailing comma problems. Next time I'm near a Windows box I'll play with this and see if there isn't a bug in Rally code lingering in there.

Comment: I'll bet this is because scripts running up on Rally for IE are made to emulate IE7-- when you run it locally, the newer IE's are past this issue.  What I have heard is this is needed because of a Dojo limitation.  But with Dojo out of the picture for the new SDK, is this something that Rally can change with the new SDK?

Comment: That looks to be it. Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize IE9 handles this differently. We are in the process of removing IE7 compatibility mode, it's getting pretty close to being gone. I can't say for sure when we'll finally turn it off though.